# update post every day

Tags: wp-cron

I'm trying to update the post information every 24 hours, and I don't know why this is not working?

```php
public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;
        add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array( $this, 'Woocommerce_G2a_cron_schedule' ));
        add_action ( 'Woocommerce_G2a_cron_hook', array( $this, 'g2aProducts' ));
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'Woocommerce_G2a_cron_hook' )) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_day', 'Woocommerce_G2a_cron_hook' );
        }
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ) );
    }

public function getProducts($id = null) {

        $g2aEmail   = 'emailaddress@domain.com'; // customer email
        $apiHash    = '#############'; // customer API hash
        $apiSecret  = '33333-44444-55555-66666-777777'; // customer API secret
        $apiKey     = hash('sha256', $apiHash . $g2aEmail . $apiSecret);
        $getPage = trim(isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'1');

        if($getPage >=1 && $getPage<=500) {
            $getPageCount = $getPage;
        } else {
            $getPageCount = '1';
        }
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://products-export-api.g2a.com/v1/products?page=$getPageCount&currency=EUR&id=$id",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Authorization: $apiHash, $apiKey",
                "Content-Type: application/json",
            )
        ));
        //Gets the API data
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $dataget = json_decode($response,true);
        return $dataget;
    }

    public function add_g2a_product() {

        $product = array(
            'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
            'post_name'    => $_POST['name'], 
            'post_title'   => $_POST['name'],
            /*'post_excerpt' => excerpt($_POST['description']),*/
            'post_status'  => 'publish', 
            'post_type'    => 'product', 
            'post_author'  => 1
        );

        $product_id = wp_insert_post( $product );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_sku', $_POST['sku'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $_POST['price'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', $_POST['price'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock', $_POST['quantity'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_g2a_product', 1 );
        return json_encode(array("error" => false, "message" => "Product added to store."));
    }
public function add_g2a_product() {

        $product = array(
            'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
            'post_name'    => $_POST['name'], 
            'post_title'   => $_POST['name'],
            /*'post_excerpt' => excerpt($_POST['description']),*/
            'post_status'  => 'publish', 
            'post_type'    => 'product', 
            'post_author'  => 1
        );

        $product_id = wp_insert_post( $product );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_sku', $_POST['sku'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $_POST['price'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', $_POST['price'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock', $_POST['quantity'] );
        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_g2a_product', 1 );
        return json_encode(array("error" => false, "message" => "Product added to store."));
    }

    public function g2aProducts() {

        $sekRate = file_get_contents("http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_SEK&compact=y&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        $sekRate = json_decode($sekRate);
        $SEK = $sekRate->EUR_SEK->val;

        $args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_g2a_product',
                    'value' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        $products = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $post_id = $product->ID;
            $sku = get_post_meta($post_id, '_sku');
            $g2a_products = $this->getProducts($sku[0]);
            foreach($g2a_products['docs'] as $g2a_product) {
                $price = round($g2a_product['retail_min_price'] * $SEK, 2);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', $price);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', $price);
            }
        }
    }
    public function Woocommerce_G2a_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
        $schedules['every_day'] = array(
            'interval' => 86400, // Every 24 hours
            'display'  => __( 'Every 24 hours' ),
        );
        return $schedules;
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of failure points in that code that aren't handled and just assumed to have been succesful, e.g. if `file_get_contents` failed, or is it returned an error instead of JSON, are you sure those weren't the parts that failed? There's no logging here so no insight into the internal workings. I also see the functions, but I don't see any scheduling code, how are these functions executed? Did you schedule the cron job? How are you testing this? I see you're not updating an existing post, but instead creating a brand new post, is this intentional?

Comment: just updated the code is this what you are asking for?

Comment: No, you've added a cron schedule type of 24 hours, but nowhere in your code is  it actually used. You've not scheduled any cron tasks in the code in your question, or told it to attach functions  to the cron hook.. Where is the call to `wp_schedule_event`? Where are the hooks added? Your code just has functions, but there's zero information about how they're called, when they're called, and no hooks

Comment: Also, you should revoke your credentials and create new ones, your API key and secret are in your question and are no longer safe to use

Comment: it´s fine it´s for sandbox

Comment: Do you have the full code for what you're working with? As I said, there's missing code, where are the hooks and cron scheduling code, and how is it called? Without this it's not possible to answer this question. If the answer is that this code does not exist, we need to know

Comment: is it safe to post the full code? without (API keys and secrets of course)